# Append to the previous line for a match

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

can I use `sed` or `awk` to append to the previous line if a match is found ?

I have  a file which has the format :

```
          INT32
          FSHL (const TP  Buffer)
             {
          INT32
          FSHL_lm (const TP  Buffer) 
          { WORD32 ugo = 0; ...
```

What I am trying to do is scan for  independant open braces `{`and append it to the previous non-blank line .The match should not occur for an open brace appended by anything in the same line .

The expected  output :

```
           INT32
          FSHL (const TP  Buffer){
          INT32
          FSHL_lm (const TP  Buffer) 
          { WORD32 ugo = 0; ...
```

Thanks for the replies .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/\n\s*{\s*$/{/;P;D' file
```

Explanation:

- `$!N` unless the last line append the next line to the pattern space.
- `s/\n\s*{\s*$/{/` replace  a linefeed followed by no or any amount of white space followed by an opening curly brace followed by no or any amount of white space to the end of the string, by an opening curly brace.
- `P` print upto and including the first newline.
- `D` delete upto and including the first newline (if so do not start a new cycle).

Comment: Works great ! Can you add a brief description to your regex :)

Answer (score 2):

One way using `perl`. I read all file in slurp mode and use a regular expression to search lines with only a curly brace and remove its leading spaces.

```
perl -ne '
    do {
        local $/ = undef;
        $data = <>;
    };
    $data =~ s/\n^\s*(\{\s*)$/\1/mg;
    print $data
' infile
```

Assuming `infile` with the content of the question, output will be:

```
FSHL (const TP  Buffer){
INT32
FSHL_lm (const TP  Buffer)
{ WORD32 ugo = 0; ...
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '!(NF == 1 && $1 == "{") { if (line) print line; line = $0; next; } { sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $0); line = line $0; } END { print line }' file.txt
```

Or broken out on multiple lines:

```
!(NF == 1 && $1 == "{") { 
    if (line) print line
    line = $0
    next
}

{
    sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $0)
    line = line $0
}

END {
    print line
}
```

Results:

```
INT32
          FSHL (const TP  Buffer){
          INT32
          FSHL_lm (const TP  Buffer) 
          { WORD32 ugo = 0; ...
```

HTH

Comment: The regexp `!/{$/` would fail if there are spaces after the curly brace. Also for a line like `[{`, because it doesn't check anything before it. Perhaps the OP can live with it but I would use the tighter `!(NF == 1 && $1 == "{")` or `!/^ *{ *$/` instead.

Comment: @Birei: Thanks, you are right. I did not consider leading chars other than whitespace ..for some reason, unknown to me.

Comment: @steve Thanks ! Works in my case ;)

Comment: What does `if (line) print line` do?

Comment: @ArchStanton: That will print the value for the 'line' variable if it has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

[shyam@localhost ~]$ perl -lne 's/^/\n/ if $.>1 && /^\d+/; printf "%s",$_' appendDateText.txt

that will work

i/p:

06/12/2016 20:30 Test Test Test

TestTest

06/12/2019 20:30 abbs abcbcb abcbc

06/11/2016 20:30 test test

i123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233Test

06/12/2016 20:30 abc

o/p:

06/12/2016 20:30 Test Test TestTestTest

06/12/2019 20:30 abbs abcbcb abcbc

06/11/2016 20:30 test ##testi123312331233123312331233123312331233123312331233Test